# How can I give "+123" to an NSNumberFormatter and not get a "NaN' back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have set up a nice NSNumberFormatter which does all the things I want, except allowing a number to be preceded by a unary "+".  It's not a common usage normally, but I'm entering latitudes and "+12.34" is sometimes used to indicate a northern latitude in the same way "-43.21" indicates southern.  Likewise for longitudes and East/West.  It may not be used every time but I don't want to make it 'illegal' -- that just annoys people.

I tried [... setLenient:TRUE] but that doesn't change this behavior.

I'm trying to not set up my own format string to avoid impacting localization.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but what happens if you use [`setPositivePrefix:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

```
[formatter setPositivePrefix:@"+"];
```

Comment: Brilliant! That does *exactly* what I want. Reminder to self: learn all the nooks and crannies of the NumberFormatter API !! Thanks.

Comment: Darn!  Sadly, in my excitement I didn't do a very good test.  Using the [... setPositive:] REQUIRES a "+" before the number, it's not an option, so that doesn't work.

Comment: @Gavin: Oh bugger, sorry about that. Although it is just as easy to strip the "+" sign, so wallyk's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a wrapper around the function which either strips the `+` or outputs it (I can't tell which conversion you're doing) as you expect it?